# Where's my ephemeral storage for EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have looked through the following questions, notably [How to use "Instance Store Volumes" storage in Amazon EC2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/433703/how-to-use-instance-store-volumes-storage-in-amazon-ec2)

However, it didn't answer. I created a EC2 small instance with EBS as the root device. The [AWS instance types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) list an "instance store" of 160GB. But where is it?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  3.6G  4.3G  46% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm

$ mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
```

So how to find the empheral store (160GB) and use it.

**Note:** I am aware of the difference between ephemeral and elastic stores. I need this space for use temporary, transient data used by the application to help with disk I/O between EBS.

#### UPDATE

Requested output per comments:

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/xvda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 202        1    8388608 xvda1
```

Comment: Run `fdisk -l` to see if there a 160G disk available. Or `cat /proc/partitions` to see if there is any xvd* disk besides xvda.

Comment: Correction. See update.

Comment: Dupe of: http://serverfault.com/questions/583289/aws-ec2-migration-to-new-instance-type-with-ssd-drives

Comment: Actually @ChrisMoschini, theirs is a dupe of mine, considering I asked first.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Fair enough. Whatever happens someone at Serverfault needs to do some cleanup - if you click over there I linked to even more dupes in the comments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

RTFM - I found my answer in the [Amazon EC2 Instance Store docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#InstanceStore_UsageScenarios).

> Instances that use Amazon EBS for the root device ***do not, by default,
>   have instance store available at boot time. Also, you can't attach
>   instance store volumes after you've launched an instance.*** Therefore,
>   if you want your Amazon EBS-backed instance to use instance store
>   volumes, you must specify them using a block device mapping when you
>   create your AMI or launch your instance. Examples of block device
>   mapping entries are: /dev/sdb=ephemeral0 and /dev/sdc=ephemeral1.

So in my case, since I choose an EBS root device, I'll need to rebuild the instance with the instance store volume.